# Removing Clock screenlet in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, cinnamon, clock

I've added a Clock screenlet (with a custom theme) on my desktop and the thing is that I can't remove it. What I can do is to add another clock, click on it and "Quit all clocks" which removes them from the screen, but I can't remove the first one individually. The problem is that usually you can click on it and it shows the menu. But in this case wherever I click it shows ordinary desktop options, so I can't select it in any way.

How can I do it, maybe there is some way of interacting with them through command line?

Comment: Which desktop environment, Mate, Cinnamon, Gnome, ...? Is the clock part of the screenlets package?

Comment: It's Cinnamon. Standard clock package with external skin.

Comment: Well I've had a similar issue with a transparent calendar screenlet, the workaround was trying to catch and rightclick a pixel which is not transparent. But I guess your clock is not transparent, isnt it?

Comment: @donschoe Yes, it is transparent and I can't catch any pixels which are not transparent.

Comment: Well with command line you can only kill all at once, removing only one wont work. If it's transparent by accident you could open the screenlets manager and click the button "reset screenlets config" and after that you should be able to add a new clock without transparency theme.

Comment: Thanks, @donschoe, that did reset all the settings and I could redo everything from the beginning. If you make it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with transparent screenlets.

One workaround is trying to catch and rightclick a pixel which is not transparent.

If this does not work you can open the `screenlets-manager` and click the button `reset screenlets config`. After that you should be able to add a new clock without transparency theme.